# "Managed Packages", can we integrate with these with an API?

Tags: force

A client has a web app which is built on the salesforce platform. They used custom objects and managed packages that are unique to a particular domain.

The client would like us to integate using APIs with their web app on the force platform. For example, filling out a form adds a new Custom Object A. Can we do this like any other Salesforce integration, or could the web app provider have restricted API access to these custom objects and managed packages.

Comment: Both are possible. Managed package objects are just namespaced objects in the org where it is installed, and are fully accessible using a range of APIs offered by Salesforce. To constrain your integration to just those objects, give the users running the integration access to just those via Profiles or Permission Sets.

Comment: To specifically restrict the integration in this way seems strange to me. What if they need to add their own data or logic to instances of a custom object from the package? What if they want to integrate data from various managed objects with their own records in pages or business logic and to do it via explicit API layer would require too many API calls in 24 hrs (since there are limits for API calls)? It seems logical to leverage all possible "integration points" to me, which includes SOQL, SOSL, Apex, flows and REST/SOAP APIs. IMHO use the tools that fit the need and the governor limits.

Comment: BTW that doesn't prevent creation of a separate part of the solution, e.g. an org-specific unlocked package, that represents the integration, to help modularize the solution.

Comment: (Sorry, I meant "org dependent" not org-specific)